# After changing settings, I can no longer get my laptop screen on (it's black). How can I see the display monitor?

Tags: laptop, display

My laptop screen went dark and I searched on how to fix this - found to disconnect power and drain it with the power button, then close the lid almost all the way and then try to hit power button (after plugging back in).  It worked! (and how anyone ever figured that out amazes me).  However, a friend told me to change the settings that say "When laptop is closed -> Do Nothing"...so I changed it to that and now the trick no longer works and I can't get in at all...bad advice!  I need my data...what can I do now?

Comment: Do you hear any sound (fan sound) is it turned on at all? Or Has it stopped working? Is your power LED /`hard disk activity LED flashing?

Comment: It sounds like your laptop backlight died.  Need answers to the above questions to help.

Comment: If you point a flashlight at the screen, and look at an angle can you see anything displayed?